# How can do screen share using restcomm?

Tags: restcomm

I am trying to implement screen share in RestComm platform. I am not able to find a suitable implementation guild.
Please help us this

Answer (score 0):

It's not yet available, see https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-web-sdk/issues/7. Feel free to help and try to contribute it though, we would gladly welcome that ;) !